# Fading edges of line/rect

Tags: svg

I have an svg `<g>` in which I have a line (can be rect too.. have tried both). This inner element has a fill/stroke that can rotate from 8 different colors or patterns. The shape is 5px height, with a dynamic width, and I should support fading left, right or both edges.

I would like to achieve this without creating extra elements on the svg and some how apply a mask/gradient but it seems I cannot get it to work.

Since the shape's X and Y, color, and width can change, I have not found a consistent way to make this happen without creating new elements with a bunch of color combinations. Does anyone have an idea on how to achieve this in the most simple and scalable way?

UPDATE
After Paul suggestion i created a fiddle to represent some how the scenario i have:
https://jsfiddle.net/0tnc9mq5/

So multiplelines/rects in same svg with different colors, positions and dimensions. What would be the way to apply some of those fades to some of those elements? How would i implement Paul's suggestion? Is there any other approach?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps add a `<linearGradient>` and then alter the `stop-color` and `offset` attributes of the individual `<stop>` elements with JavaScript?

Comment: Thanks Max but then the same linearGradient is used for different elements and i would have to create one gradient for each element to avoid changing another's fades

Comment: Perhaps loop through each of the rects/lines in JavaScript, and dynamically generate a mask/gradient for each one, which you could then append to the `<svg>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it, using masks to produce the fading ends.  The fades are fixed in this example to be 10% of the length of the line.

We create a shared SVG that contains `<symbol>` elements for each of the three variants you need.  That only needs to appear once in your HTML.

Then anywhere you want one of the separators, include the mini SVG corresponding to the separator you desire.  You can set the width, height and colour of the separator using CSS.

```css
svg.sep {
  width: 500px;
  height: 5px;
}

.one {
  color: red;
}

.two {
  color: green;
}

.three {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="gleft">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="black"/>
      <stop offset="10%" stop-color="white"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="gright">
      <stop offset="90%" stop-color="white"/>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="black"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="gboth">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="black"/>
      <stop offset="10%" stop-color="white"/>
      <stop offset="90%" stop-color="white"/>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="black"/>
    </linearGradient>
    
    <mask id="mleft">
      <rect width="1" height="1" fill="url(#gleft)"/>
    </mask>
    <mask id="mboth">
      <rect width="1" height="1" fill="url(#gboth)"/>
    </mask>
    <mask id="mright">
      <rect width="1" height="1" fill="url(#gright)"/>
    </mask>

    <symbol id="left" viewBox="0 0 1 1" preserveAspectRatio="none">
      <rect width="1" height="1" fill="currentColor" mask="url(#mleft)"/>
    </symbol>
    <symbol id="both" viewBox="0 0 1 1" preserveAspectRatio="none">
      <rect width="1" height="1" fill="currentColor" mask="url(#mboth)"/>
    </symbol>
    <symbol id="right" viewBox="0 0 1 1" preserveAspectRatio="none">
      <rect width="1" height="1" fill="currentColor" mask="url(#mright)"/>
    </symbol>
  </defs>
</svg>


<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>

<svg viewBox="0 0 1 1" preserveAspectRatio="none" class="sep one">
  <use xlink:href="#left"/>
</svg>

<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>

<svg viewBox="0 0 1 1" preserveAspectRatio="none" class="sep two">
  <use xlink:href="#right"/>
</svg>

<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>

<svg viewBox="0 0 1 1" preserveAspectRatio="none" class="sep three">
  <use xlink:href="#both"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks Paul, i've update my question with a fiddle as an example of muy current scenario. Do you think of anyway to implement your solution on that case? Thanks

Comment: So your lines are all in one SVG?  I assumed you wanted something like custom `<hr>`s for your HTML.

Comment: The masks I have defined in my example (with a slight tweak) will work just fine with your set of `<rect>` elements.  You just need to copy the definitions into your SVG and apply them to the rects.  https://jsfiddle.net/0tnc9mq5/1/